# how to extract isosurface from PDE result ？

Tags: matlab, math, pde

```
thermalmodel = createpde('thermal');
importGeometry(thermalmodel,'model.stl'); 
pdegplot(thermalmodel,'FaceLabel','on','FaceAlpha',0.5)
axis equal
thermalProperties(thermalmodel,'ThermalConductivity',80);
thermalBC(thermalmodel,'Face',2,'Temperature',50);
thermalBC(thermalmodel,'Face',5,'Temperature',300);
mesh=generateMesh(thermalmodel);
thermalresults = solve(thermalmodel);
```

I try the following way

```
x=mesh.Nodes(1,:);
y=mesh.Nodes(2,:);
z=mesh.Nodes(3,:);
[X,Y,Z] = meshgrid(x,y,z)
isosurface(X, Y, Z, Temperature, 100);
```

there are 27021 nodes,meshgrid(x,y,z)will need huge memory，27021x27021x27021 (146992.2GB),matlab cant work it out or I use the method in a wrong way.

Comment: Hello! Welcome to stackoverflow. This is an interesting question; however, we highly discourage using the sentence "it does not work". It's too vague. How does it not work? Does it crash? Is there an error message? Does it return a result which is wrong? Does it run for too long without returning a result?

Comment: Also, you used the C++ tag, but this doesn't appear to be related to C++?

Comment: I am sorry ,I haven`t used it for a long time. thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled that the first part of the code ends with `thermalresults = solve(thermalmodel);`, but the second part of the code makes no direct mention of `thermalresults` nor `thermalmodel`. Are the effects of `solve` automatically reverberated on `mesh`?